# R combine / merge two columns to one column

Tags: r

I have two columns (class: character) in a data.frame that include large numbers (e.g. column A: 999967258082532415; columns B: 999967258082532415). I want a new columns C that combines the two numbers:999967258082532415999967258082532415

I use:

```
data_1$visit_id <- do.call(paste, c(data_1[c("post_visid_high", "post_visid_low")], sep = ""))
```

But my new column gets converted to factor, but I still want a character. What can i do?

Comment: Can we see a sample of your data frame?

Comment: put `options(stringsAsFactors=F)` on top of your code and run it. somewhere you are running data.frame command, since default is stringsAsFactors =T , hence might be your data is converting to factors

Comment: `paste0(data_1$post_visid_high, data_1$post_visid_low)`

Comment: PKumar: where is "on top". Could you please insert the whole code?

Comment: @flobrr , Top means First line should be this `options(stringsAsFactors=F)` , then  you run your all the commands in R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample dataset that resembles yours:

```
df <- data.frame(col_A = c(2314325435454354,123098213728903214,12329042374094), 
             col_B = c(9034832054097390485,30945743504375043,234903284304))
```

Using dplyr, create a new column (column C) that concatenates the other two columns, followed by mutating all columns to character data type:

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>%
    mutate(col_C = col_A + col_B) %>%
    mutate_all(funs(as.character(.)))
```